# Android XMLSerializer namespace exception

Tags: android, xml

I'm using XMLSerializer to write xml but i keep coming across an exception that doesn't explain much, can you help?

```
09-25 10:46:31.733: WARN/System.err(23654): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: </{}titleid> does not match start
09-25 10:46:31.944: WARN/System.err(23654):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlSerializer.endTag(KXmlSerializer.java:504)
```

Exception occurs in the following KXmlSerializer.java

```
public XmlSerializer endTag(String namespace, String name)
                throws IOException {

            if (!pending)
                depth--;
            //        if (namespace == null)
            //          namespace = "";

            if ((namespace == null && elementStack[depth * 3] != null)
                    || (namespace != null && !namespace
                            .equals(elementStack[depth * 3]))
                    || !elementStack[depth * 3 + 2].equals(name))
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("</{" + namespace + "}"
                        + name + "> does not match start");
```

any ideas?

```
private String writeXml(List<Message> messages){
XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
try {
    serializer.setOutput(writer);
    serializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
    serializer.startTag("", "messages");
    serializer.attribute("", "number", String.valueOf(messages.size()));
    for (Message msg: messages){
        serializer.startTag("", "message");
        serializer.attribute("", "date", msg.getDate());
        serializer.startTag("", "title");
        serializer.text(msg.getTitle());
        serializer.endTag("", "title");
        serializer.startTag("", "url");
        serializer.text(msg.getLink().toExternalForm());
        serializer.endTag("", "url");
        serializer.startTag("", "body");
        serializer.text(msg.getDescription());
        serializer.endTag("", "body");
        serializer.endTag("", "message");
    }
    serializer.endTag("", "messages");
    serializer.endDocument();
    return writer.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above examlple is completely correct but the actual code i used had two endTags that were the same without starting (startTag) the second tag...

My error

thanks